# Issue when saving app.config with heterogeneous ConfigurationElementCollection items

Tags: c#, winforms, configuration, app-config, configurationmanager

I have an application that reads the app.config of a separate application. The app.config contains a collection of heterogeneous elements. The application I'm building will generate a TreeView control that displays the app.config custom section. the Save() method of the configuration object works fine unless I drill down and read/display the contents of the custom section. I followed [this](http://snippetrepo.com/snippets/heterogeneous-configuration-collections-in-c) as an example (also found [here](https://gist.github.com/Antaris/1664214)). The issue seems to be that when I'm saving (after viewing and regardless if I make changes to the underlying config) the GetElementKey method is called. This returns the Key value of the element collection. But then this value is passed to the CreateNewElement method. This causes a problem because CreateNewElement passes back a new type depending on what elementName is passed in. At this point the element name isn't being passed in, just the key value.

The other strange thing I've noticed, from stepping through the code several times, is that if I don't read the values from the config to build the UI to display them, I hit the GetElementKey twice per element in the collection and CreateNewElement is not called at all. What happens when I do display values is that GetElementKey is called the same number of times. However, it comes back and is called again and then CreateNewElement is called with the key value as described above. Hopefully someone can describe to me what's going on under the hood that's causing this sequence of events to occur. Is there a property I need to change when deserializing the xml to the configuration objects?

This is the way I have my app.config structured:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="section1" type="example" />
  </configSections>
  <section1>
    <node1>
      <elementA name="anElement" />
    </node1>
    <node2>
      <add key="1" value="foo" />
    </node2>
    <node3>
      <elementB>
        <elementC name="anElement"/>
        <elementD >
          <elementE>
            <foo name="foo1" />
            <bar name="bar1" />
          </elementE>
          <elementF>
            <elementG />
          </elementF>
        </elementD>
      </elementB>
  </section1>
</configuration>
```

The issues is regarding the collection in node section1/node3/elementD/elementE. After GetElementKey is called on "foo" and "bar" (2 times each) then it is called again and "foo1" is passed to CreateNewElement and that's when things break down.